# Appending/adding custom data (hidden) to a html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So html elements can have attributes which will say something about the element. However, these attributes are visible to anyone which could be bad if the data stored is sensitive.  So can you store data in/on a html element with javascript/jquery or something else?

Like (using jQuery) if I had a #apple div and wanted to append a secret data (red) to it. Could I do something with this logic?:

```
$("div#apple").secret = "red";
or 
$("div#apple").data = { "color": "red" };
alert("The color of an apple is " + $("div#apple").secret);
```

I'm guessing one way to do this is create a jQuery function to bind to the html element and then bind the data to that function, but is there an easier/better way of pulling something like this off?

Also, I know that html 5 allows custom attributes, is there any version of html that allows/does the above without javascript/jquery?

Comment: you mean you want to add SECRET data to something client-side open-source codes like javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [jQuery's `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is what you need. It stores the data in a key-value way.

You can use it in this way:

```
$('.where').data('key', 'value');
$('.where').data('dog', {'name': 'fritz'});
```

And then you can retrieve it in this way:

```
$('.where').data('key'); // value
$('.where').data('cat'); // null, nothing exists with the cat key
$('.where').data('dog'); // object, {'name': 'fritz'}
```

It works storing all the data you what in its internal object `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: man i wish i googled this harder before i asked my question... :), is there a way of doing this that is built in just html though?

Comment: No, with plain HTML you can't do that. Note that even jQuery `.data` is secure at all, because you're sending sensitive stuff which will be stored on the client in an un-encrypted way.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) functionality for this, e.g.

```
$("#apple").data("color", "red");

var color = $("#apple").data("color"); // "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method can be used to store arbitrary data on an element. If there is no `data-*` attribute that matches the name used present on the element itself, jQuery will store the data internally and it should not be visible through any DOM inspector.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/vDvhw/).

However, you should be aware of the fact that anything client side will always be visible to the user, no matter how hard you try to hide it. If you have "secret" data, the safest place for it is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you can use your own attributes in HTML tags, like . The document won’t validate, but browsers will just ignore attributes that they don’t recognize; this has been the practice in HTML since the early days.

However, to avoid clashes with standard attributes, browser-specific attributes, and future extensions to them, it would be a good idea to use the HTML5 convention of “data-* attributes,” e.g. .

As you say that you are looking for something “without javascript/jquery,” I suppose this would be for use with something like a specialized indexing robot—at least some robots for site-wide search systems use extra attributes. In that case, check that the parsing routine of the robot accepts an attribute name containing a hyphen “-” (some naive parsers might fail to do that).

The data would of course be available to anyone who uses e.g. View Source. If the data is sensitive, it should not appear in HTML source. In some cases, you might consider including an identifying number or string that acts as an index to information stored securely on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is pretty safe approach.
But remember, finally the value would be stored in Browser memory. I am sure there must be ways to sniff this.
Remember 1 thing, if you want some thing to be safe, do not put in on net.